# SQL Server : bulk Insert and ignore duplicates

Tags: insert, duplicates, bulk

I'm trying to do a bulk insert (SQL Server 2008) into a table but the insert must ignore any duplicate already in the table.

The simplified table will look like this with existing values.

```
TBL_STOCK

id | Stock
---------------
1  | S1
2  | S2
3  | S3
```

Now I want to do a bulk insert that looks like

```
INSERT INTO TBL_STOCK (Id, Stock)
VALUES 
(3, S3),
(4, S4),
(5, S5)
```

This works but will cause duplicate entries

How do I go about ignoring duplicate entries in the `Stock` column?

Answer (score 0):

By "ignoring duplicate entries", you mean avoiding them in TBL_STOCK, right ?

I might be a bit late, but have you tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO #TempStock (Id, Stock) -- temporary table
VALUES 
(3, S3),
(4, S4),
(5, S5)

INSERT INTO TBL_STOCK
SELECT * FROM #TempStock 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Stock FROM #TempStock WHERE #TempStock.Stock = TBL_STOCK.Stock)

DROP TABLE #TempStock
```